# What can I do instead of this that's better, for my smart pointers?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

What the question asks. I know this works, but is it good practice or bad practice? Another example that I've seen someone use, and I've been using it myself, but it doesn't feel right.

```
// in some header file

template <class T>
class ptr {
private:
    T* pointer;
public:
    explicit ptr (T* p = NULL) : pointer(p) { }
    ~ptr()                                  { delete (pointer); }
    T& operator *()                         { return *pointer; }
    T* operator ->()                        { return pointer; }
};
```

```
// in some source file, probably main.cpp
ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());

function(foo->self()); // using function(foo) doesn't work because it can't
                       // convert ptr<Foo> to Foo*
```

```
// somewhere inside definition of Foo
Foo* self() { return this; }
```

Why wouldn't it work unless I included the `self()` function, and how can I pass the object into the function without it?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is typecast overloading? https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-typecasts/

Comment: I would consider it bad practice for a lot of reasons, the first is that `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` already exist in the Standard Library. You are also in blatant violation of the Rule of 5.

Comment: `T* self() { return pointer; }` would be what you want, in your pointer class. You want to expose the *pointer*, not your object. In a `std::unique_ptr`, this is the `.get()` function.

Comment: "I know this works". [Doesn't look like it](https://godbolt.org/z/7WTn7e83s).

Comment: `NULL` in lieu of `nullptr` would be another, less obvious thing, you'd best avoid. But it's moot of course, should you use a standard pointer type instead of writing one on your own. The standard `std::unique_ptr` is about as efficient as one can write such a type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a pointer type getter.

```
template<typename T>
class ptr {
...

  const T* get() const { return pointer; }
  T* get() { return pointer; }
}

function(foo->get());
```

- Avoid using `new`. Create a maker function like `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`.
- Create Copy/Move constructor/assignment operator. Make correct behavior on each operations.
- Add const accessor

Answer (score 0):

Automatic conversion from `ptr<Foo>` fo `Foo*` is possible:

```
template <class T>
class ptr {
    private:
        T* pointer;
    public:
        operator T*() { return pointer; }
    // rest of code
```

but having it would defeat the idea of smart pointers, so smart pointer classes from the standard library do not include it. Instead, they have something like

```
    T* get() { return pointer; }
```

so that such conversions are explicit.

Most of the time you should just use one of the standard library classes. If you need to create your own smart pointer, it is recommended to avoid the inclusion of `operator T*()` (and avoid automatic conversions in general).